# Reattach ID column to data after passing through sklearn model

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am working on trying to create a predictive regression model that forecasts the completion date of a number of orders.

My dataset looks like:

```
| ORDER_NUMBER | Feature1 | Feature2 | Feature3 | Feature4 | Feature5 | Feature6 | TOTAL_DAYS_TO_COMPLETE | Feature8 | Feature9 | Feature10 | Feature11 | Feature12 | Feature13 | Feature14 | Feature15 | Feature16 | Feature17 | Feature18 | Feature19 | Feature20 | Feature21 | Feature22 | Feature23 | Feature24 | Feature25 | Feature26 | Feature27 | Feature28 | Feature29 | Feature30 | Feature31 |
|:------------:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------:|:----------------------:|:--------:|:--------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|
|   102203591  |    12    |   2014   |    10    |   2014   |     1    |   2015   |           760          |    50    |    83    |     5     |     6     |     12    |     18    |     31    |     8     |     0     |     1     |     0     |     1     |     16    |   131.29  |  24.3768  |   158.82  |    1.13   |    6.52   |     10    |     51    |     39    |     27    |     88    |  1084938  |
|   102231010  |     2    |   2015   |     1    |   2015   |     2    |   2015   |           706          |    35    |    34    |     2     |     1     |     4     |     3     |     3     |     3     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |     2     |   11.95   |   5.162   |   17.83   |    1.14   |    3.45   |     1     |     4     |     20    |     16    |     25    |   367140  |
|   102251893  |     6    |   2015   |     4    |   2015   |     3    |   2015   |          1143          |    36    |    43    |     1     |     2     |     4     |     5     |     6     |     3     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     1     |     5     |    8.55   |   5.653   |   34.51   |    4.59   |    6.1    |     0     |     1     |     17    |     30    |     12    |   103906  |
|   102287793  |     4    |   2015   |     2    |   2015   |     4    |   2015   |           733          |    45    |    71    |     4     |     1     |     6     |     35    |    727    |     6     |     0     |     3     |     15    |     0     |     19    |   174.69  |   97.448  |   319.98  |    1.49   |    3.28   |     20    |    113    |     71    |     59    |     71    |  1005041  |
|   102288060  |     6    |   2015   |     5    |   2015   |     4    |   2015   |          1092          |    26    |    21    |     1     |     1     |     3     |     2     |     2     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     2     |    4.73   |   4.5363  |   18.85   |    3.11   |    4.16   |     0     |     1     |     16    |     8     |     16    |   69062   |
|   102308069  |     8    |   2015   |     6    |   2015   |     5    |   2015   |           676          |    41    |    34    |     2     |     0     |     3     |     2     |     2     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     2     |    2.98   |   6.1173  |    11.3   |    1.36   |    1.85   |     0     |     1     |     17    |     12    |     3     |   145887  |
|   102319918  |     8    |   2015   |     7    |   2015   |     6    |   2015   |           884          |    25    |    37    |     1     |     1     |     3     |     2     |     3     |     2     |     0     |     0     |     1     |     0     |     2     |    5.57   |   3.7083  |    9.18   |    0.97   |    2.48   |     0     |     1     |     14    |     5     |     7     |   45243   |
|   102327578  |     6    |   2015   |     4    |   2015   |     6    |   2015   |           595          |    49    |    68    |     3     |     5     |     9     |     11    |     13    |     5     |     4     |     2     |     0     |     1     |     10    |   55.41   |  24.3768  |   104.98  |    2.03   |    4.31   |     10    |     51    |     39    |     26    |     40    |   418266  |
|   102337989  |     7    |   2015   |     5    |   2015   |     7    |   2015   |           799          |    50    |    66    |     5     |     6     |     12    |     21    |     29    |     12    |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |     20    |   138.79  |  24.3768  |   172.56  |    1.39   |    7.08   |     10    |     51    |     39    |     34    |    101    |  1229299  |
|   102450069  |     8    |   2015   |     7    |   2015   |    11    |   2015   |           456          |    20    |    120   |     2     |     1     |     3     |     12    |     14    |     8     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     7     |    2.92   |   6.561   |    12.3   |    1.43   |    1.87   |     2     |     1     |     15    |     6     |     6     |   142805  |
|   102514564  |     5    |   2016   |     3    |   2016   |     2    |   2016   |           639          |    25    |    35    |     1     |     2     |     4     |     3     |     6     |     3     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     3     |    4.83   |   4.648   |   14.22   |    2.02   |    3.06   |     0     |     1     |     15    |     5     |     13    |   62941   |
|   102528121  |    10    |   2015   |     9    |   2015   |     3    |   2016   |           413          |    15    |    166   |     1     |     1     |     3     |     2     |     3     |     2     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     2     |    4.23   |   1.333   |   15.78   |    8.66   |   11.84   |     1     |     4     |     8     |     6     |     3     |   111752  |
|   102564376  |     1    |   2016   |    12    |   2015   |     4    |   2016   |           802          |    27    |    123   |     2     |     1     |     4     |     3     |     3     |     3     |     0     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     3     |    1.27   |   2.063   |    6.9    |    2.73   |    3.34   |     1     |     4     |     14    |     20    |     6     |   132403  |
|   102564472  |     1    |   2016   |    12    |   2015   |     4    |   2016   |           817          |    27    |    123   |     0     |     1     |     2     |     1     |     1     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |    1.03   |   2.063   |    9.86   |    4.28   |    4.78   |     1     |     4     |     14    |     22    |     4     |   116907  |
|   102599569  |     2    |   2016   |    12    |   2015   |     5    |   2016   |           425          |    47    |    151   |     1     |     2     |     4     |     3     |     4     |     3     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     2     |   27.73   |  15.8993  |    60.5   |    2.06   |    3.81   |     12    |    108    |     34    |     24    |     20    |   119743  |
|   102599628  |     2    |   2016   |    12    |   2015   |     5    |   2016   |           425          |    47    |    151   |     3     |     4     |     8     |     8     |     9     |     7     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     2     |     8     |   39.28   |  14.8593  |   91.26   |    3.5    |    6.14   |     12    |    108    |     34    |     38    |     15    |   173001  |
|   102606421  |     3    |   2016   |    12    |   2015   |     5    |   2016   |           965          |    55    |    161   |     5     |     11    |     17    |     29    |     44    |     11    |     1     |     1     |     0     |     1     |     22    |   148.06  |  23.7983  |   195.69  |     2     |    8.22   |     10    |     51    |     39    |     47    |    112    |  1196097  |
|   102621293  |     7    |   2016   |     5    |   2016   |     6    |   2016   |           701          |    42    |    27    |     2     |     1     |     4     |     3     |     3     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |     2     |    8.39   |   3.7455  |   13.93   |    1.48   |    3.72   |     1     |     5     |     14    |     14    |     20    |   258629  |
|   102632364  |     7    |   2016   |     6    |   2016   |     6    |   2016   |           982          |    41    |    26    |     4     |     2     |     7     |     6     |     6     |     2     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |     4     |   26.07   |   2.818   |   37.12   |    3.92   |   13.17   |     1     |     5     |     14    |     22    |     10    |   167768  |
|   102643207  |     9    |   2016   |     9    |   2016   |     7    |   2016   |           255          |     9    |    73    |     3     |     1     |     5     |     4     |     4     |     2     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |    2.17   |   0.188   |    4.98   |   14.95   |   26.49   |     1     |     4     |     2     |     11    |     1     |   49070   |
|   102656091  |     9    |   2016   |     8    |   2016   |     7    |   2016   |           356          |    21    |    35    |     1     |     0     |     2     |     1     |     1     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |    1.45   |   2.0398  |    5.54   |    2.01   |    2.72   |     1     |     4     |     14    |     15    |     3     |   117107  |
|   102660407  |     9    |   2016   |     8    |   2016   |     7    |   2016   |           462          |    21    |    31    |     2     |     0     |     3     |     2     |     2     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     2     |    3.18   |   2.063   |    8.76   |    2.7    |    4.25   |     1     |     4     |     14    |     14    |     10    |   151272  |
|   102665666  |    10    |   2016   |     9    |   2016   |     7    |   2016   |           235          |     9    |    64    |     0     |     1     |     2     |     1     |     2     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |   0.188   |    2.95   |   10.37   |   15.69   |     1     |     4     |     2     |     10    |     1     |   52578   |
|   102665667  |    10    |   2016   |     9    |   2016   |     7    |   2016   |           235          |     9    |    64    |     0     |     1     |     2     |     1     |     2     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |    0.72   |   0.188   |    2.22   |    7.98   |   11.81   |     1     |     4     |     2     |     10    |     1     |   52578   |
|   102665668  |    10    |   2016   |     9    |   2016   |     7    |   2016   |           235          |     9    |    64    |     0     |     1     |     2     |     1     |     2     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |    0.9    |   0.188   |    2.24   |    7.13   |   11.91   |     1     |     4     |     2     |     10    |     1     |   52578   |
|   102666306  |     7    |   2016   |     6    |   2016   |     7    |   2016   |           235          |    16    |    34    |     3     |     1     |     5     |     5     |     6     |     4     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     3     |   14.06   |   3.3235  |   31.27   |    5.18   |    9.41   |     1     |     1     |     16    |     5     |     18    |   246030  |
|   102668177  |     8    |   2016   |     6    |   2016   |     8    |   2016   |           233          |    36    |    32    |     0     |     1     |     2     |     1     |     1     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |    2.5    |   5.2043  |    8.46   |    1.15   |    1.63   |     0     |     1     |     14    |     2     |     4     |   89059   |
|   102669909  |     6    |   2016   |     4    |   2016   |     8    |   2016   |           244          |    46    |    105   |     4     |     11    |     16    |     28    |     30    |     15    |     1     |     2     |     1     |     1     |     25    |   95.49   |   26.541  |   146.89  |    1.94   |    5.53   |     1     |     51    |     33    |     9     |     48    |   78488   |
|   102670188  |     5    |   2016   |     4    |   2016   |     8    |   2016   |           413          |    20    |    109   |     1     |     1     |     2     |     2     |     3     |     2     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |    2.36   |   6.338   |    8.25   |    0.93   |    1.3    |     2     |     1     |     14    |     5     |     3     |   117137  |
|   102671063  |     8    |   2016   |     6    |   2016   |     8    |   2016   |           296          |    46    |    44    |     2     |     4     |     7     |     7     |    111    |     3     |     1     |     0     |     1     |     0     |     7     |   12.96   |   98.748  |   146.24  |    1.35   |    1.48   |     20    |    113    |     70    |     26    |     9     |   430192  |
|   102672475  |     8    |   2016   |     7    |   2016   |     8    |   2016   |           217          |    20    |    23    |     0     |     1     |     2     |     1     |     2     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |    0.5    |   4.9093  |    5.37   |    0.99   |    1.09   |     0     |     1     |     16    |     0     |     1     |   116673  |
|   102672477  |    10    |   2016   |     9    |   2016   |     8    |   2016   |           194          |    20    |    36    |     1     |     0     |     2     |     1     |     1     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |    0.61   |   5.1425  |    3.65   |    0.59   |    0.71   |     0     |     1     |     16    |     0     |     2     |   98750   |
|   102672513  |    10    |   2016   |     9    |   2016   |     8    |   2016   |           228          |    20    |    36    |     1     |     1     |     3     |     2     |     2     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |    0.25   |   5.1425  |    6.48   |    1.21   |    1.26   |     0     |     1     |     16    |     0     |     2     |   116780  |
|   102682943  |     5    |   2016   |     4    |   2016   |     8    |   2016   |           417          |    20    |    113   |     0     |     1     |     1     |     1     |     1     |     1     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     1     |    0.64   |   6.338   |    5.53   |    0.77   |    0.87   |     2     |     1     |     14    |     5     |     2     |   100307  |
```

The `ORDER_NUMBER` should not be a feature in the model -- it is a unique identifier that I would like to essentially not count in the model since it is just a random ID, but include in the final dataset, so I can tie back predictions and actual values to the order.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_feature_importances(cols, importances):
    feats = {}
    for feature, importance in zip(cols, importances):
        feats[feature] = importance

    importances = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(feats, orient='index').rename(columns={0: 'Gini-importance'})

    return importances.sort_values(by='Gini-importance', ascending = False)

def compare_values(arr1, arr2):
    thediff = 0
    thediffs = []
    for thing1, thing2 in zip(arr1, arr2):
        thediff = abs(thing1 - thing2)
        thediffs.append(thediff)

    return thediffs

def print_to_file(filepath, arr):
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        for item in arr:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)

# READ IN THE DATA TABLE ABOVE        
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# create the labels, or field we are trying to estimate
label = data['TOTAL_DAYS_TO_COMPLETE']
# remove the header
label = label[1:]

# create the data, or the data that is to be estimated
data = data.drop('TOTAL_DAYS_TO_COMPLETE', axis=1)

# Remove the order number since we don't need it
data = data.drop('ORDER_NUMBER', axis=1)

# remove the header
data = data[1:]

# # split into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, label, test_size = 0.2)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(
    bootstrap = True,
    max_depth = None,
    max_features = 'sqrt',
    min_samples_leaf = 1,
    min_samples_split = 2,
    n_estimators  = 5000
)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
rf_predictions = rf.predict(X_test)
rf_differences = compare_values(y_test, rf_predictions)
rf_Avg = np.average(rf_differences)
print("#################################################")
print("DATA FOR RANDOM FORESTS")
print(rf_Avg)
importances = get_feature_importances(X_test.columns, rf.feature_importances_)
print()
print(importances)
```

If I `print(y_test)` and `print(rf_predictions)` I get something like:

```
**print(y_test)**
7
155
84
64
49
41
200
168
43
111
64
46
96
47
50
27
216
..

**print(rf_predictions)**
34.496
77.366
69.6105
61.6825
80.8495
79.8785
177.5465
129.014
70.0405
97.3975
82.4435
57.9575
108.018
57.5515
..
```

And it works. If I print out `y_test` and `rf_predictions`, I get the labels for the test data and the predicted label values.

However, I would like to see what orders are associated both the `y_test` values and the `rf_predictions` values. How can I keep that dataset and create a dataframe (like below):

```
| Order Number | Predicted Value   | Actual Value |
|--------------|-------------------|--------------|
| Foo0         | 34.496            | 7            |
| Foo1         | 77.366            | 155          |
| Foo2         | 69.6105           | 84           |
| Foo3         | 61.6825           | 64           |
```

I have tried looking [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594894/adding-scikit-learn-sklearn-prediction-to-pandas-data-frame) but I could not get a solution. I did try `print(y_test, rf_predictions)` and that did not do any good since I have `.drop()` the `ORDER_NUMBER` field.

Comment: Are the indexes the same? That is, that `order_number[0]` corresponds to `predicted_value[0]` and `actual_value[0]`? If so, then concatenate them across, perhaps like `pd.DataFrame([order_number, predicted_value, actual_value], columns=['Order Number', 'Predicted Value', 'Actual Value'])`

Comment: I don't know if they are. My understanding is that `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` randomizes the data, so I don't think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using pandas dataframes the index is retained in all your x/y train/test datasets, so you can re-assemble it after you applied the model. We just need to save the order numbers before dropping that column: `order_numbers = data['ORDER_NUMBER']`. The predictions `rf_predictions` are returned in the same order as the input data to `rf.predict(X_test)`, i.e. `rf_predictions[i]` belongs to `X_test.iloc[i]`.

This creates your required result dataset:

```
res = y_test.to_frame('Actual Value')
res.insert(0, 'Predicted Value', rf_predictions)
res = order_numbers.to_frame().join(res, how='inner')
```

Btw, `data = data[1:]` doesn't remove the header, it **removes the first row**, so there's no need to remove anything when you work with pandas dataframes.

So the final program will be:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_feature_importances(cols, importances):
    feats = {}
    for feature, importance in zip(cols, importances):
        feats[feature] = importance

    importances = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(feats, orient='index').rename(columns={0: 'Gini-importance'})

    return importances.sort_values(by='Gini-importance', ascending = False)

def compare_values(arr1, arr2):
    thediff = 0
    thediffs = []
    for thing1, thing2 in zip(arr1, arr2):
        thediff = abs(thing1 - thing2)
        thediffs.append(thediff)

    return thediffs

def print_to_file(filepath, arr):
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        for item in arr:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)

# READ IN THE DATA TABLE ABOVE        
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# create the labels, or field we are trying to estimate
label = data['TOTAL_DAYS_TO_COMPLETE']

# create the data, or the data that is to be estimated
data = data.drop('TOTAL_DAYS_TO_COMPLETE', axis=1)

# Remove the order number since we don't need it
order_numbers = data['ORDER_NUMBER']
data = data.drop('ORDER_NUMBER', axis=1)

# # split into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, label, test_size = 0.2)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(
    bootstrap = True,
    max_depth = None,
    max_features = 'sqrt',
    min_samples_leaf = 1,
    min_samples_split = 2,
    n_estimators  = 5000
)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
rf_predictions = rf.predict(X_test)
rf_differences = compare_values(y_test, rf_predictions)
rf_Avg = np.average(rf_differences)
print("#################################################")
print("DATA FOR RANDOM FORESTS")
print(rf_Avg)
importances = get_feature_importances(X_test.columns, rf.feature_importances_)
print()
print(importances)

res = y_test.to_frame('Actual Value')
res.insert(0, 'Predicted Value', rf_predictions)
res = order_numbers.to_frame().join(res, how='inner')
print(res)
```

With your example data from above we get (for `train_test_split` with `random_state=1`):

```
    ORDER_NUMBER  Predicted Value  Actual Value
3      102287793         652.0746           733
14     102599569         650.3984           425
19     102643207         319.4964           255
20     102656091         388.6004           356
26     102668177         475.1724           233
27     102669909         671.9158           244
32     102672513         319.1550           228
```

Comment: Thanks @Stef. I'm confused. Doesn't the `random_state` parameter of `train_test_split` randomize the dataset? So how would the then appending of the order numbers back to that be accurate? The `ORDER_NUMBER` column was not specified in the shuffle.

Comment: `random_state` just seeds the random number generator; I only included it here to make this example reproducible. If you leave this parameter out, you'll get different lines with each run from `train_test_split` which is fine, so it has nothing to do with your question. I explained in the first paragraph how it works. It's true that `ORDER_NUMBER` is not included in the shuffle, but the index of your pandas dataframes is. Just run the code and print X_train, X_test, y_train and y_test to see it.